# Determining asymptotic notions for functions

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

For these two instances of functions $f$ and $g$, I need to decide if $f= \Theta (g)$, $f= \omega (g)$ or $f=o(g)$.

1. $f(n)=\displaystyle\left( \frac {\ln(n+4)\ln(\ln(n))}{\ln(n)}\right)^{\ln(n)}$, $g(n)= 16^{\ln(\ln(n))}$
2. $f(n)=n^{n+1}e^{-n}$, $g(n)=(n+1)!$

Re 2., I got to $f=o(g)$ using the Stirling's approximation, but I am not sure that I'm right.

Comment: I wonder if you accidentally  mis-read $\log(x+4)\log \log n$ as $\log [\log (n+4)\log\log n]$ to get $f=o(g).$

Answer (score 1):

We have $\frac {\log (n+4)}{\log n}> 1,$ so for all sufficiently large $n$ we have $f(n)>(\log \log n)^{\log n}$ and $\log f(n)>(\log n)(\log\log \log n)>\log n.$ But $\log g(n)=(\log \log n)(\log 16)$, so $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\log f(n)}{\log g(n)}=\infty.$ And $g(n)\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty.$  Therefore $g(n)=o(f(n)$ as $n\to \infty.$ More strongly, for any $K>0$ we have $g(n)^K=o(f(n))$ as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: Then $f= \omega(g)$.